# Admob ads don't load if initilized after Applovin

Tags: android, admob, applovin

In my "ad mediation" I first try to load Applovin ads and if it has no fill, then to load Admob:

```
//AppLovinAdLoadListener
public void failedToReceiveAd(int arg0)
{
    loadAdmob();
}
```

But for some reason, Admob ads don't load and neither callback `onAdLoaded()` nor `onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode)` of Admob is fired.

Has anybody experienced that?

Comment: Does `failedToReceiveAd` get called? Try putting a log message here to verify. Assuming it does, then the problem is something with your `loadAdmob` method, and you should provide us the code to that here too :)

Comment: Instead of mediating yoruself you are better off using a mediation platform like the one Admob provides natively and choose appLovin first then Admob (or whatever other network you want).